# i want to implement material ui carousel in my project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, carousel

I want to implement Material-UI carousel in my project.

I tried `install`ing it and `import`ed it, but running the project errors with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

AutoRotatingCarousel.render
C:/Users/55590i5 D'/Desktop/react-website-v2-master/node_modules/material-auto-rotating-carousel/lib/AutoRotatingCarousel.js:249
 
  247 | var landscape = mobile && landscapeProp;
  248 | var transitionDuration = { enter: _transitions.duration.enteringScreen, exit: _transitions.duration.leavingScreen };

> 249 | var hasMultipleChildren = children.length != null;
      | ^  250 | 
  251 | var carousel = _react2.default.createElement(
  252 |   _SwipableCarouselView2.default,
```

Error is in the line 249.

Comment: Can you give us more details? Maybe a codesandbox?

Comment: Can you check to children's value? Which type of children?